# Using GoogleAPIClient with tvOS

Tags: swift, google-calendar-api, tvos, google-api-client, gtm-oauth2

I want to use `GoogleAPIClient/Calendar` pod in a tvOS app. My problem is that `GTMOAuth2` is an iOS-only pod. How can I authenticate my user without `GTMOAuth2`? Is it possible to access Google Calendar's api with tvOS, and if so how?

Thanks!

Comment: Short Answer = You cant authenticate with Google without OAuth. However, take a look at [this](http://stephenradford.me/oauth-login-on-tvos/). He shows how you can authenticate over a device.